# How to install to tablet

Tags: android

Can I install Ubuntu like desktop version to my xiaomi mi pad?instead of android. Im very interested in. Please ,help me. Thank you

Comment: Hardware questions are off topic. If it does google will tell you but you will at least need firmware for that machine (that Canonical does not provide so you need a 3rd party). Try the xda developers site ;)

Comment: A quick search shows quite a few sites that might help for ex. http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/  but as other comments here say this is off-topic here, we would not want to give you advise that would brick your tablet....